# How Apache Karaf sorts bundles to install and start?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, apache-karaf

I have defined four bundles:

```
bundle 1 : export package x version 1
bundle 2 : import package x ver [1,2] and export package y;y uses x    
bundle 3 : export package x version 2
bundle 4 : import package y and also import package x version 2
```

Using apache felix (distribuable binary), I found that I should manually impose to not resolve (or start) the bundle 1 and then bundle 2 before starting the bundle 3 (otherwise a uses constraint problem appears because bundle 2 will use package x version 1 and in bundle 4 will appear package x version 1 and version 2 --> uses constraint violation).
Thanks to the authors of these posts:
http://njbartlett.name/2011/02/09/uses-constraints.html
http://blog.springsource.com/2008/10/20/understanding-the-osgi-uses-directive/
I don't like to impose order to my bundles, I need to copy all my bundles in the /bundle directory and then the instance of framework install and start them.
I noticed that Apache felix sorts the bundles to be installed alphabetically (so bundle 1 will be installed and then started the first).
I tried with Apache karaf, I copied my bundles into /deploy and I found that the problem disappears, so my question is:

Does Apache Karaf, (or felix file install) apply a strategy to impose any order for starting bundles in order to avoid these kind of problems ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to use a Karaf feature for this kind of deployment. You create a feature file with one feature in it and add all the bundles to this feature. Karaf will then load all the bundles and resolve and start them in one pass. So the resolver should bee able to correctly resolve all your bundles.

Comment: Thank you Christian Schneider for the clarification,  
So, if I understand, I can define a **Karaf feature** as a set of bundles that will be started when I install and start the feature, and the Karaf container will apply a strategy to correctly resolve these bundles avoiding the "uses constraint violation" ??
  
If true, can you please explain what does **Karaf** to determine the best order of resolving the bundles, that is not done by felix ?

Thanks

Comment: Karaf just uses the felix features to resolve the bundles. The main difference to fileinstall is that it can resolve the bundles as a complete set instead of installing the bundles individually. For an example for a feature see: https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/tasklist

Comment: Thank you for the example, I have already seen, it really helps :)  
Other question please, so, defining a **Karaf feature** allows to start all the feature's bundles in one passage, but no order is calculated, and for example, returning to the example that I have put, Karaf may install the four bundles, and resolve them in the order ( b1 then b2 then b3 then b4), which throws the exception in question ?
Is this the case ? and is it similar to copying all these bundles in the /deploy directory before launching the container (so the felix file-install will retrieve them in the same poll) ?

Comment: Because even using the distribuable binary of Apache **Felix**, and by copying the bundles in the /deploy directory, felix will resolve them in one passage (installs all the bundles and then returns to start them one by one) and we will always find this error ? And the same when using *felix file-install* and putting all those bundles in the watched directory at the same instant (hence the same poll)

Comment: Apache Karaf does not create a special order to avoid package use conflicts, this is the duty of the felix resolver. It sounds as if your case is not covered in the resolver but I am not sure about the inner workings of it. 
In any case the safe solution for your would be to avoid the package use. If the bundle is developed by you then perhaps you can solve this using better encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Karaf does automatically add a startlevel to the bundles in the deploy folder this is configurable. The default of it is 50. So all your custom bundles are installed as StartLevel 50. This also makes sure the basic bundles of karaf itself are already up and running, especially the file-installer bundle.

Comment: Thank you for your response :)
My problem is in the order of these bundles in the deploy folder, do you hava explanation ?

Comment: I don't think start level is relevant... in this case it's a problem with install/resolve order.

Comment: As Neil pointed out one problem is that fileinstall polls the directory in a certain intervall. If you have half your bundles copied to the deploy folder and fileinstall poll kicks in then it will only deploy half of your bundles.

Answer (score 0):

Felix FileInstall does not have any ordering capability.

Start order isn't really important (bundles *should* be able to be started in any order), but a good Management Agent should be able to install and resolve a batch of bundles as a single operation. However FileInstall installs/resolves/starts bundles whenever it happens to poll the filesystem directory. Therefore FileInstall is not really usable for production deployment.

I don't know anything about Karaf, but any management agent that simply polls a directory is likely to have the same problem.